# React Navigation and React Native Gesture Handler -- Invariant Violation: No callback

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, monorepo, react-native-gesture-handler

I have been experimenting mono repositories with javascript, using react and react-native applications. However, I have been having some problems using external dependencies on a simple react-native application.

While trying to integrate react-navigation following this guide [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/), I always end up with a lot of errors like:
**ERROR    Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 18929 and callID 9464 for module . Args: '[1131]'**

It even gets in loop. This starts happening when I import `react-native-gesture-handler` at `index.js`. I have been trying to understand the problem for days and tried a lot of different stuffs, since `nohoist` of dependencies, clearing dependencies, reset react-native caches, watchman links and so on. However, I always end up in this error.

I have been experimenting with it on ios.

I am not sure it is a problem with the libraries I have mentioned here, because if I have a standalone react-native project, I can use the `react-native-gesture-handler`.

So, initially, I thought it was a problem with the mono repository structure I have, however, I have tried to use other libraries like: `styled-components`, `react-native-router`, `react-native-restart`, and `react-native-contacts`, and those libraries work well.

Has anyone passed for this problem? I have a github repository [here](https://github.com/joaoantunes87/monorepo/tree/react-navigation) where I try to explain how to reproduce the error.

I have also been documenting, to my self, my experimentations with mono repositories [here](https://just-code-joaoantunes.netlify.app/), step by step, in case it gives more context.

I do not know if it is the best place to make this question, however I do not know where to look more, any suggestion is welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: I keep working on it and after while, I think I could pass it, following the suggestions here:
https://engineering.brigad.co/react-native-monorepos-code-sharing-f6c08172b417

However, I am getting different problems in another project. My example could be seen here:
https://github.com/joaoantunes87/monorepo/compare/react-navigation?expand=1

Comment: https://github.com/joaoantunes87/monorepo/pull/1